# How find if a number is the sum of 2 perfect squares?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I'm looking for a way to find if a number is the sum of 2 perfect squares.
given x find if there exists non negative integers a, b, m, n such that:

$a^m + b^n = x$

Comment: Two sentences in your question ask two completely different things.

Answer (score 1):

Fermat said that N = x^2 + y^2 for some integers x, y iff in the prime factorization of N the primes of the form 4k + 3 occurs an **even** number of times. Example: 245 = 5*7*7 and 7 =4*1 + 3 is a prime of the form 4k+3 occurs twice. We see that 245 = 7^2 + 14^2. The more extensive case with m,n > 2 can be a lot harder.

Comment: Matik Ken, http://oeis.org/A070049 i found this sequence on OEIS but i cant figure out how to convert that into a HLL source code.